# Sending passwords securly over the net: javascript?

Tags: tls, javascript

I believe SSL is decrypted and encrypted from your computer to the receiver right? Well is it possible to use any type of encryption (Stanford crypto lib?) to get a password safely over the net these days?

Well bulk password collection ISP side of course...

And what if people started a movement thing to get an "Extension" for (Chrome, Firefox etc)  of some sorts that could hold the library so a later MITM attack to load malicios javascript would not be possible?

Comment: what is the question? what do you want to protect from?

Comment: bulk isp parsing of passwords i guess or something

Answer (score 1):

Properly implemented TLS provides end-to-end encryption between the client (your computer) and the server so that any passwords being sent should not be visible to any passive attacker along the wire.  TLS also resists active attacks by require that certificates be verified by Certificate Authorities.  If you are the server operator, you can make future man in the middle attacks harder by implementing [Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).  STS ensures that future connections by the same user agent will also connect over an encrypted channel, and enhances certificate errors on future connections (generally, users will not see a "proceed anyway" option if the SSL connection is being tampered with).